# How can i withdraw from FTX exchange using the REST API in Python?

Tags: python, api

i have check their REST API and couldn't found the way to withdraw for example ( **ETH** ) .

i found only function for withdraw with Fiat but there is no function to withdraw cryptocurrencies coin .

i am using the **Python** version ( REST API ) .

Comment: I think you're better off asking the FTX exchange itself. You are not encountering any issues that we can help with here.

Answer (score 0):

You might check this [ftx official docs](https://docs.ftx.com/#request-withdrawal) for help.

Also check [ccxt](https://github.com/ccxt/ccxt) which is a helpful toolkit for writing crypto exchange scripts.